# Field api, defining new fields and getting/setting values

Tags: drupal

I'm able to create a field, using

```
$form['title'] = array( '#type' => 'text', '#value' => 'Drupal');
```

1) But I want to be able to get/set the value from the database. How would I do it?

2 )P.S. what's the point of having a '#" in front of type and value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I don't know what Drupal version are you using.
Secondly try to get some more info from the my answer:

1) Use [Database API](http://drupal.org/node/310069) in order to get values from database.

2) Read more about [Form API](http://drupal.org/node/37775).

Hope this helps.